# How can i send audio file from GCS (Google Cloud Storage) URL in terminal using CurL?

Tags: node.js, express, curl, google-cloud-storage

For example (which it doesn't work...)

```
curl -d https://storage.googleapis.com/storage-xx-xx/xx.wav http://XX.XX.XX.XX/api/XX/upload`
```

I'm here trying to upload files from GCS bucket to a API server inside the terminal. The reason i am doing this is because app engine  (read-only) is preventing me download file onto a tmp folder.

I know the best way is to directly post request with the audio to the API from the browser. But right now, the API server didn't enable CORS. So I texted the backend team regarding the issue. But at the mean time, i would like to know could i implement something like the above example? I apologize for the incoherent sentences....

in summary:

1. curl "google-cloud-storage" "api-address"
2. possible?

Comment: Don't bother with curl.  Use gsutil.  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature is not available for Cloud Storage however I strongly suggest that you submit it as a feature request [1].

A possible walk around would be to use the Gsutil cp [2] command using your Cloud Storage object’s path as the src_url and the dst_url would be a local or Cloud instances which would then send it to the API Server.

[1]http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=1162869
[2]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp